# Single value in constructs vs argument list for construction

Tags: c++, c++11

This question pertains to this [code snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d64a2752a07dc380) reproduced below:

```
struct A { 
    A():b(0) { } 
    A(const A&, int b = 0):b(b) { } 
    int b; 
};

int main() {
  A a;

  const A& a1 = { a };  
  const A& a2 = { a, 1 };
  a.b = 2;   
  std::cout << a1.b << a2.b << std::endl;
}
```

The right hand side of the assignment of a1 can be a single value in constructs or an argument list for construction.  Is there anywhere in the standard that specifies which interpretation takes precedence?  For a2, it is a construction of a temporary A whose address is assigned to a2, if I did not misunderstand.

BTW, compiling this code by clang++ in Coliru produced output 21.  gcc++-4.8 output 01.

Comment: Oh boy. You're in for a treat. Welcome to this mess :)

Comment: Isn't using `a1` and `a2` anywhere UB, since they are const references to a temporary?

Comment: @stefan the life of those 2 objects is prolonged until end of scope

Comment: @BЈовић Ah yes of course. It's imprinted in my brain to never do this and only this warning flag came up in my sleepy brain. Thanks

Comment: I see you have been messing with it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of list-initialization has changed quite a bit since the publication of the C++11 Standard due to defect reports.

From draft n3485 (after the Standard has been published, with some corrections but without C++1y features) [dcl.init.list]/3

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> - If `T` is an aggregate [...]
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of `std::initializer_list<E>` [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a class type [...]
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type `E` and either `T` is not a reference type or its referenced type is reference-related to `E`, the object or reference is initialized from that element; if a narrowing conversion is required to convert the element to `T`, the program is ill-formed.
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by `T` is list-initialized, and the reference is bound to that temporary
> - [...]

In the latest draft from the Committee's github repo (ce016c64dc), only a slight change applies here to one point [dcl.init.list]/3:

> - Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by `T` is copy-list-initialized or direct-list-initialized, depending on the kind of initialization for the reference, and the reference is bound to that temporary.

From draft n3242 (before the Standard) [dcl.init.list]/3:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> - If the initializer list has no elements [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is an aggregate [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of `std::initializer_list<E>` [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a class type [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a reference to class type or if `T` is any reference type and the initializer list has no elements, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by `T` is list-initialized, and the reference is bound to that temporary.
> - [...]

(I don't have a copy of the Standard itself right now.)

---

Let's assume your compiler implements the proposed resolutions to the defect reports. Then, the first example

```
const A& a1 = { a };
```

initializes like `const A& a1 = a;` (no temporary); and the second example

```
const A& a2 = { a, 1 };
```

initializes like `const A& a2 = A(a,1);`.

Answer (score 1):

> **8.5.4/3** List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>   ...
>
> - Otherwise, if T is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by T is list-initialized, and the reference is bound to
>     that temporary.

In your example, `a1` does not bind directly to `a`, but to a temporary copy-constructed from `a`.